# How to delete a portion of PDF?

Tags: pdf, editor

Long time ago, I used an online tool that generated a report in PDF. I do not have access to that tool anymore. I need to share the PDF with someone, but need to cover or delete a small portion of text that is confidential.

I tried importing the document into ms word to remove the confidential text (it is just a few lines) but unfortunately, the pervious formatting was affected and I could not use this option.

Is there a way or a tool that would allow me to do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool for deleting some pages.

https://smallpdf.com/delete-pages-from-pdf

Comment: Thanks, but this is just a few lines inside one page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems not possible to only remove or redact a portion of text since PDF is not designed to do that. Even if you managed to insert a rectangle to blot out the text it could be still recovered with authoring tools. However, you can still remove the pages containing sensitive information if that helps.

Edit 1: [SmallPDF](https://smallpdf.com/) provides tools to draw boxes on pages and delete pages. It might worth a try. But it's cloud-based, and you have to upload your PDF onto their server for editing which could be a security concern. Other desktop solutions (like Acrobat, Foxit PDF Editor etc.) either require a subscription or simply doesn't have the ability to draw boxes on arbitrary position.

Comment: Thanks, could you say which tool may be used to add a rectangle on top of those few lines? I may give it a try.

Comment: Drawing boxes over text may superficially hide it but that text can still be extracted from the document, often by simple copy and paste. Thus, that is no solution for confidential data.